# Android Talkback stops on async page update (accessibility screen readers)

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, screen-readers, talkback

Testing for accessibility: I have an Angular app that async refreshes its content on a regular interval. When I visit a page in Chrome and play Talkback, the talkback will stop upon the async refresh.

This makes sense (we don't want it reading old data) but leaves me hanging a little bit.  The screen reader simply stops and may be jarring or confusing upon readback.  In addition it may be difficult for users to reorient themselves on the page.

Is it possible to have Talkback simply restart itself or at least hook into the "stop" event to maybe notify the person that they need to restart.

An abstract example of the code:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">
<td>My name is {{ user.name }}</td>
<td>My favorite thing is {{ user.favorite }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The screen reader stopping coincides with either an update to user.name or refresh in users.

So depending on when the async happens it might say something like:

`"My name is Julie, cell." (stops)`

`"My name is Julie, cell. My favorite thing is" (stops)`

Answer (score 0):

This is standard behaviour for screenreaders. You can use the [aria-live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) attribute to mark the updating region so screenreaders know what to do with it. I'd probably also offer a [pause button](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/time-limits-pause.html) for the updates because many users with cognitive impairments find content that regularly changes very distracting when they are trying to complete a task.